# sprintf in LLVM IR

Tags: printf, llvm-ir, libc

I'm trying to use the `sprintf` function in my LLVM IR program. However, Clang (Windows 10) always gives me an exception saying that the definition for "sprintf" cannot be found.

Here's how I declared it:
`declare void @sprintf(ptr, ptr, ...)`

I also looked at how a C program that uses sprintf does it, but it just defines a ton of functions that I don't understand (vsprintf, _snprintf, _vsnprintf, _vsprintf_l, _vsnprintf_l, etc.).
Why is that and how can I do it (without copying all those functions)?

Comment: Did you link with libc?

Comment: How? I thought it’s linked automatically as I can access many other functions